# How to get the remainder of a dataset

Tags: matlab

Below is an example of choosing a set number of random permutations from a dataset, how can I create a new dataset with the remaainder. For example below I choose 49402 (roughly 10%) and create a dataset named `UnseenTestdata` after this is chosen I want the remainder to go into a new dataset called `testdata`.

```
pointsToPick = 49402;  %# Numbers to pick
rVec = randperm(494021);   %# Random permutation of datapoint indices (N=494021 in this case)  

UnseenTestdata = fulldata(rVec(1:pointsToPick),:); %# Random sample
```

Unseentestdata minus fulldata = remainder of the dataset aptly named testdata.

Dimensions of fulldata set is 494021x6 of which I choose at random 49402x6 from fulldata. I then need to get whats left from fulldata minus the unseentestdata.

Barnabas Szabolcs added a test case answer of:

```
fulldata = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8];
rVec = randperm(4);  
pointsToPick=2;
unseen = fulldata(rVec(1:pointsToPick),:); 
testdata = fulldata(rVec(pointsToPick:length(rVec)),:);
```

However this does not work, I have screen dumped the results:

[image]

If you notice in the screen dump unseen data = 3,4 and 7,8 however if you notice in testdata 7,8 remain.

If fulldata =

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
```

And we choose two random rows in this case the rows in unseen are:

```
row
3,4
7,8
```

Then whatever remains should be:

```
1,2
5,6
```

However if you notice in the sreen dump from the example test testdata has the row:

```
7,8
```

showing that the example test does not work.

Comment: you mean setminus here don' you? can you also add the dimensions of fulldata?

Comment: updated my answer, also added test case to verify.

Comment: I hope you checked my answer again, sorry I was sloppy with those parentheses. Plus updated the test case too, since it had a speciality that the number of remaining elements and the second dimension of the full data were equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution is

```
testdata = fulldata(rVec((pointsToPick+1):length(rVec)),:);
```

Simple test case:

```
fulldata = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8;10 9];
rVec = randperm(4);  // gives me first time [4 2 3 1 5]
pointsToPick=2;
unseen = fulldata(rVec(1:pointsToPick),:); // [7 8; 3 4]
// length(rVec) is 5
testdata = fulldata(rVec((pointsToPick+1):length(rVec)),:); // [5 6; 1 2; 10 9]
```

you can clearly see that in a sense `fulldata` = `unseen` (setplus) `testdata`.
Note that we need "+1" because arrays are indexed from one up unlike say in c++, so the last index is `length` not `length-1`.

You can verify if things are correct using this:

```
 isequal(sort([unseen; test]), sort(full_data)) // should be true
```

Comment: hmm something is fishy with that, the output for testdata is 444620 when it should be 444619.

Comment: haha you cant just do +1, can you? I need the data to be exact i.e unseentestdata minus fulldata = remainder. It might require indexing unseentestdata. Length etc probably isnt what I want.

Comment: Added test example, it pretty much does what you described.
Other Downvoter: can you please clarify why you downvoted?

Comment: then pointsToPick:length would have worked in your first example if that was the case? Not pointsToPick+1

Comment: if the length of points to pick is 2 and the indices are like you say then shouldnt the testdata = whats left?

Comment: Yes, I missed there the parentheses, now it should work, sorry :)
corrected in the answer, too.

Comment: Now, not only in the test case... I was sloppy here sorry again

Comment: Ah ok, I still cant get my head around why +1 is needed?

Comment: Because that is the next index.
say rVec=[4 1 2 3 5] then rVec(1:2) -> [4 1], rVec(3:length(rVec)) -> [2 3 5], unlike in say c++, where the first element is zero so the last element is size()-1.

Comment: Also if the input arrays are the same type and size and hold the same content then I will get the answer 1 back for isequal? Which I did? I dont think isequals is correct here?

Comment: is there a way I can track the indices of unseentestdata and testdata from fulldata?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19679/discussion-between-barnabas-szabolcs-and-jungle-boogie)