# Indices of a matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, row, indices

I can't seem to get the indices of UnseenTestdata and Testdata from fulldata in the example below, can anyone help?

```
pointsToPick = 49402;  %# Numbers to pick
rVec = randperm(494021);   %# Random permutation of datapoint indices (N=494021 in this case)  

UnseenTestdata = fulldata(rVec(1:pointsToPick),:); %# Random sample
Testdata = fulldata(rVec((pointsToPick+1):length(rVec)),:);
```

I need to have a list of the row numbers from fulldata that unseentestdata came from and the same with testdata. This relates to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430173/how-to-get-the-remainder-of-a-dataset), without the indices I cant figure out which classlabels go with the unseentestdata and the testdata.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209904/find-given-row-in-a-matrix

Comment: Isn't `rVec(1:pointsToPick)` already the list of the row numbers from `fulldata` that `UnseenTestdata` came from? (same for `rVec((pointsToPick+1):length(rVec))` and `Testdata`)

Comment: @Tobold Yes, but the user told me he needed a different method. We've discussed it in a chat on his previous question.

Comment: Does `fulldata` contain duplicates? This might be what is causing the repeating rows using Barnabas' answer below. What would be your expected output in case of duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `rVec(1:pointsToPick)` which already stores the indices as @Tobold said, the other way is

```
[~,indx_uns]=ismember(UnseenTestdata, fulldata, 'rows');
[~,indx_test]=ismember(Testdata, fulldata, 'rows');
```

Note that the first return parameter is not used (thus marked by `~`).
`indx_uns(n)` gives the corresponding row of fulldata to the n-th row of UnseenTestdata.

Moreover [here is a link to the related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209904/find-given-row-in-a-matrix).

For more help on ismember: see [this link](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html)

Comment: I think you have forgotten [~,indx_uns], just typed ismember.
This is due to the fact that ismember returns two values: membership === repeating ones in your case, and indices. updated the answer

Comment: how do you use rVec(1:pointsToPick) to check the indX of unseen and test data?

Comment: have a look on @Tobold's comment ;)

Comment: I think that must be some other issue. This question does not involve files.

Comment: ughhhhhhhhh I was trying to open rVec not indx when i was doing it, and for some reason it crashes. Now when I do indX = rVec(1:pointsToPick)'; and open "indX" all is fine... man I shouldnt pull all nighters!